# Different databases for specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, testing, activerecord, rspec

I want to run most my RSpec-s **agains blazing fast SQLite**, but be able to **"tag" particular specs to use PostgreSQL** (due to the heavy use of features of PG).

this is approx what I need:

```
describe "something" do
  it "runs against SQLite by default" do
    # etc
  end

  it "but this against PG", :pg do
    # etc
  end
end
```

I can probably hack in the `establish_connection` but want to do it "right" so the models don't share any of the stuff between the two.

Another issue is how to run rake tasks against those 2 DBs.

Please **NOTE**, I'm not asking about using multiple databases from the app. I want to **switch DB between** the specs.

There gotta be a gem for that :)

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm trying to tackle the same issue and would love to hear how this turned out.

Comment: I'm just using the same DB as the production environment so that I don't need this at all. Ended up much better in the end as I could easily use DB specific syntax without problems.

Comment: Yep, we ended up switching to a [structure.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560150/what-is-db-development-structure-sql-in-a-rails-project) file so SQLite is no longer an option. Agreed that this is much better, and with a few performance tweaks (disabling logging and garbage collection in tests, etc.) the tests aren't that bad. Good to hear there's a fellow Postgres comrade out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use this solution:

[Rails RSpec with Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528868/rails-rspec-with-multiple-databases)

Basically in your before(:each / :all) connect to the other database and in your after(:each / :all) restore the default connection.