# Newbie's attempt to connect to two databases in one application in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Continue to try to make the ability to connect to multiple databases in one application in Rails.  This capability is a specific production requirement and I am a complete newbie...

So I took a prior recommendation.  Note that I could not get the application to read the 'deals_qa' environment from the database.yml, or at least this is how it appeared.

Right now, the end result is that it's sending me to an Application generated 'Oops' page, which, I'm assuming, was created to account for any errors, so nothing specific as far as why this isn't working.

Please review and provide any suggestions, or other things that I should  could be looking at to get this working... Thanks!

Here is the code changes based on previous recommendation:

This is the new model file, named 'dealsdb':

```
module Dealsdb

@abstract_class = true

conn = { :adapter => 'mysql',
 :encoding => 'utf8',
 :reconnect => 'true',
 :database => 'deals_qa',
 :username => 'xxxxxx',
 :password => 'xxxxxx',
 :host => 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
 :port => 'xxxx'
}

establish_connection(conn["deals_qa"])

end
end

class Members < Dealsdb::Base

  def email_exists?(email)
    unless email.blank? || SYSTEM_EMAILS.include?(email)
    returning find_by_email(email) do |user|
    end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the corresponding code snippet in the existing Account Controller file, file name Account_Controller.rb.  Note that I'm just trying to get past the first condition.

```
if Dealsdb::Members.email_exists?(@email)
            @Redirect_Flag = true
        else
            flash.now[:error] = 'Didnt MMS database check didnt work'
        end
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`. The way I would do this is to have my models inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` (the norm in rails). Then inside the model change the connection with `establish_connection(db_name)`.

Example:

```
class Members < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:foo)

  def email_exists?(email)
    unless email.blank? || SYSTEM_EMAILS.include?(email)
    returning find_by_email(email) do |user|
    end
    end
  end
end
```

In database.yml:

```
foo:
  adapter: mysql
  host: localhost
  database: deals_qa
  username: xxxxxx
  password: xxxxxx
```

Here's a reference link I found: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/OpHh6FdNELo

Answer (score 0):

There is a previous question speaking to connecting to multiple databases in Rails

[Rails RSpec with Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528868/rails-rspec-with-multiple-databases/1528956#1528956)

I references Rspec but the pattern works in general and I have used it successfully many times.

Comment: Thanks!  I swear that I've looked, and tried, every possible variation and it still will not connect to the secondary database...at a complete loss...  Sure I'm missing some simple syntax or method call but so far, no luck in finding the solution.